# vs2005 general error C10100b1(C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, release

I'm ready to release my *.exe and set the release build in virtual studio 2005, but I got a error like that:

mt.exe: failed to load file "..\release\hasm.exe" {_~0 **BEL SUB EOT BEL** v **STX**

the **BOLD** string with 3-characters are symbol that can not print in plain text, and I can't copy them from my working conputer, but I edited them in Notepad++, and I can see them, now I typed them in "plain" text(and ther is no space(' ') between them) and I hope you can emagin their shape.

the trick is that, I can compile my debug-edition and the *.exe works well, I have tried other project and used the same encoding and there is nothing happened -- everything goes well with the debug and release.

I think there was some unicode in the code(some comments are Chinese), but the compiler should not stand along with the code, there must be a syntax error or something else. Now, it's not a syntax error or a link error, is there any other possibilities---I mean in my code? and what exactly the mt.exe doing?

ps: I have seached for all my code, there is no "{_~" in my (C++)code, FML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the project settings for release got broken somehow. Compare all settings between the debug and release configs. If you can't find anything, it's probably something internal in the project. The best way to fix that is to create a new project in the same solution and add all your source files to it.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Sebastiaan

Comment: Actually I did the reconstruct step as your suggestion, and as you expect the problem gone. But I still do not understand what happened to to project.

Comment: Project files tend to get corrupted once in a long while. Fortunately it does not happen often. As far as I know it's impossible to reproduce so very hard for MS to fix. My guess is that it will stay a mystery forever. :)

Comment: I've had the same problem when I was playing with project settings, the error appeared after changing _Linker - Output File_ option to an empty string, then changing this setting to `$(TargetPath)` the problem disappears (in my case).